# how to install azerothcore Module such as buffer npc module

Tags: azerothcore

I already run server with azerothcore realm is already running.

I use Ubuntu 18.04 and MySql 5.7

I want to know how to install module such as mod npc buffer ,

Someone teach me step by step and please answer below question

when i run ./acore-installer No. 7 to search module and then No. 8 to install module and then what menu I choose for active module No.1? its reinstall my server right? data will be delete or not.

or

I must be install module before installing the server core

Please tell me step by step

sorry for my bad English writing skill

Thank you very much. >> azerothcore.org

Best regards,
Nyein Chan Htoo
Yangon, Myanmar

Answer (score 0):

I never used the installer to install a module (I only use the db-assembler).

To install a module in a more manual way, just follow the instructions on the repository readme.

Basically, you `git clone` the module in `modules/`. Then you rerun Cmake (because you added new files) and then you compile again.

Once compiled, you eventually apply the SQL files from the `sql` directory and then you can edit the module configuration files and launch the worldserver.